# Can I provide a relative deps path in my bazel target?

Tags: build, dependencies, filepath, directory-structure, bazel

When I specify build rules in bazel, my dependencies are either full paths (from the root of the repo), or just the target name (since its in the same directory):

```
cc_binary(
    name = "program",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],
    deps = ["//a/full/path/to/the/library:lib",
            "foo"]
)
```

Assume I'm writing a build rule from directory `"the"`.
I was hoping to do something like this:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "program",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],
    deps = ["library:lib",
            "foo"]
)
```

This does not seem to be possible.  Is there some kind of way, where I can specify the target deeper starting from the location of the BUILD file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot.

> Relative labels cannot be used to refer to targets in other packages;
> the repository identifier and package name must always be specified in this case.

From [Bazel labels documentation](https://bazel.build/concepts/labels)

Comment: That's probably a good decision on bazel's part, but still an inconvenience in some situations.